# form submit not taking the autofill value to the next page

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to take to take the value of search textbox to next page as a result of autocomplete. But it only takes the value that has been typed into the search box.

The code that i am using is:

```
function fill(thisValue) {
        var abc = $('#search').val(thisValue);
        alert(abc);
        $('#rad').show();
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
        document.getElementById("Form1").submit();
    }
```

html:

```
<form action="<?php echo $mainUrl?>/search" method="post" name="Form1" id="Form1" onsubmit="if( ( document.getElementById( 'search' ).value === '' ) || ( document.getElementById( 'search' ).value === 'Search billions of items at the single Platform' ) ){ document.getElementById( 'search' ).focus(); return false;};">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search billions of items at the single Platform" id="search" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" autocomplete='off' value="" />
                <input type="submit" name="submit_btn" value="search" class="button" id="button"   />
                <div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;">
                <img src="<?php echo $mainUrl?>/resources/autocomplete/autoComplete/upArrow.png" style="position: relative; top: -12px; left: 30px;" alt="upArrow" />
                <div class="suggestionList" id="autoSuggestionsList">


and html

<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search billions of items at the single Platform" id="search" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);" onblur="fill();" autocomplete='off' value="" />
```

Any suggestions on this will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you add the html and css of the input you are changing the value of

Comment: Please find the css and html. Also you can have a look at http://www.dailybargains.com by typing into the search box.

Comment: ok sorry, didn't want the form - just the input and the styles applied to the input, but if you look at your `blur` on the input you can see you are calling `fill()` and passing nothing in so you set the value of `#search` to be nothing in your function

Comment: Pete have a look at http://www.dailybargains.com and type something in search box then click on any autofill result. t

Comment: Pete please have a look at http://www.dailybargains.com. Type something in search box and click on any item generated as a result of autocomplete. Then you would get what problem i an getting

Comment: ok your problem is that you are calling your submit on blur, the blur event is happening as soon as you click out of the textbox meaning you don't have chance to click on the auto select list meaning nothing is selected

Comment: Can you suggest what can be done in this case

Comment: what autocomplete are you using? there must be an event for after something is selected, you can then submit your form in that event

Comment: Pete i am using this autocomplete http://www.nodstrum.com/2007/09/19/autocompleter/ could you suggest now

Comment: as it turns out you need your blur event then! instead of submitting the form where you do try something like this: setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide('fast', function() {document.getElementById("Form1").submit();});", 200);

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are calling `abc`.

If you want to alert `thisValue`, then you will write it like this:

```
alert(thisValue);
```

To take a value to next page, you can use:

```
<form action="search.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="search">`
  <input type="sbubmit" value="search">`
</form>
```

And to get search value in search PHP:

```
<?php
  $searchValue = $_POST["search"];`
  echo $searchValue;`
?>
```

Comment: I alerted as you suggested.Firstly it alerts the correct value and then it alerts undefined